# How to monitor keepalived daemon using nagios

Tags: nagios

I would like to monitor whether keepalived daemon itself is up in my network topology, using nagios 
.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by writing two perl scripts which use SNMP to query the realtime status of keepalived.  One script checks the VRRP subsystem and the other script checks the IPVS subsystem.  The check scripts are available on the Nagios Exchange.

- [check_keepalived_vrrp](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/SNMP/Keepalived-VRRP/details)
- [check_keepalived_ipvs](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/SNMP/Keepalived-IPVS/details)

The scripts can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/alaskacommunications/nagios_check_keepalived).

Answer (score -3):

Write your own script to monitor it. Deploy it on nagios with correct user & execute permission. nagios will do the rest.